# How to find same values in a list column and concatenating strings on the other rows for the same column value

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List with 2 columns with the following structure:

```
50 process:3333
50 phone:xxxx
51 process:2222
51 phone:yyyy
```

I need to build a new list based on that first one with this structure:

```
50 process:3333,phone:xxxx
51 process:2222,phone:yyyy
```

Does List have any method to find from one column a same value and concatenate the string on second column.

Or I have to find a way to do it manually using a foreach or a while statement?

Comment: in GridView control of asp.net webpage, you can refer to DataBound event and 2 attribute: DataKeys and DataKeyNames. Hope this help

Comment: What kind of app is this? ASP, WPF, WinForms, Console? What's the actual control type you're using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a simple struct like...

```
public struct Proc
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

with your sample data:

```
var procList = new List<Proc>() { 
    new Proc{ID=50,Value="process:3333"},new Proc{ID=50,Value="phone:xxxx"},
    new Proc{ID=51,Value="process:2222"},new Proc{ID=51,Value="phone:yyyy"},
};
```

You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy` and `String.Join`:

```
var procIdGroupList = procList
    .GroupBy(p => p.ID)
    .Select(g => new Proc
    {
        ID = g.Key,
        Value = string.Join(",", g.Select(p => p.Value))
    }).ToList();
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/XyP1oq)**

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for that:

```
//Recupera valores dos indices para o tipo de documento
                List<Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.imports> valuesList = new List<Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.imports>();
                var valuesListObj = from a in context.sistema_Documentos
                                    join b in context.sistema_Indexacao on a.id equals b.idDocumento
                                    join c in context.sistema_Indexes on b.idIndice equals c.id
                                    where a.ativo == 1
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        id = a.id,
                                        values = c.idName + ":" + b.valor
                                    };

                var çist = (from x in valuesListObj.AsEnumerable()
                            select new Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.imports
                            {
                                id = x.id,
                                values = x.values
                            }).ToList();

                var importList = çist.GroupBy(p => p.id).Select(g => new Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.imports
                                                                        {
                                                                            id = g.Key,
                                                                            values = string.Join(",", g.Select(p => p.values))
                                                                        }).ToList();
```